# How can I click on a button inside an iframe using Selenium and Python

Tags: selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to click on a button "Administration" inside an iframe but I'm getting this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Python code I am using:

```
main = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='main absolute']")
main.click()
driver.switch_to.frame("tab_Welcome")
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.wah-global-ask-banner-item div.wah-global-ask-banner-item-title.wah-global-ask-banner-item-title-paa")))
button.click()
```

HTML:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Administration** as the the desired elements are within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.iframe-content#tab_Welcome")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.wah-global-ask-banner-item-title.wah-global-ask-banner-item-title-paa"))).click()
    ```
  - `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='iframe-content' and @id='tab_Welcome']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='wah-global-ask-banner-item-title wah-global-ask-banner-item-title-paa' and text()='Administration']"))).click()
    ```
  - **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    ```

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Answer (score 2):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()` 
Induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable()` and Following XPATH.

```
main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='main absolute']")))
main.click()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"frame_Welcome")))
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Administration']")))
button.click()
```

Comment: It didn't work, still got the timeout error, it wasn't able to click on 'main absolute'

Comment: @Luiz : Sorry my mistake.Missed the parenthesis.Try now.

Comment: well clicking on main worked, but i'm still getting the same error for the administration button

Comment: @Luiz : Can it possible to share url?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're switching to the `iframe` using its ID, but you need to switch to it by name.

So instead of `driver.switch_to.frame("tab_Welcome")`

You should try `driver.switch_to.frame("frame_Welcome")`

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is an existing `ExpectedCondition` that handles waiting for a frame, `EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`. See KunduK's answer.

Comment: @Luiz It's possible the issue is with the CSS selector itself which is causing the timeout, even if you successfully switched to the iframe. It looks like @KunduK has implemented a correct XPath selector that you can use: `//div[text()='Administration']`

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_all_iframes(driver):
    iframes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe")
    for index, iframe in enumerate(iframes):
        # Your sweet business logic applied to iframe goes here.
        driver.switch_to.frame(index)
        find_all_iframes(driver)
        driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
```